# Custom Office 365 log in Page without Windows Azure subscription

Tags: office-365, login

I want to customize office 365 log in page to match corporate needs.
It has to be done without Azure subscription or Azure account upgrade.
Please suggest work around for this.

It will be fine if i can redirect user to another log in page and then authenticate to site using username and password and redirect them back to my office 365 site home page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) or another federation provider.

Microsoft has a host of resources available regarding ADFS setup and configuration.  link to ADFS custom login pages on TechNet:
[Customizing the AD FS Sign-in Pages](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280950.aspx)

ADFS can be customized with some simple assets and PowerShell.  That is you don't directly modify the login pages but provide image assets, css, and javascript via PowerShell.

Other federation providers will have their own options around customizations. some of these like ADFS can be configured on-site.  Others are hosted providers. There is  link on MSDN with information on using some of the more popular services and products here: 
[Azure AD federation compatibility list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj679342.aspx)

Two of the more used options are:

- CA Site Minder
- IBM Tivoli Identity Manager

Comment: Hi, can you please add more details around this answer? As it stands now it is more of a comment. Maybe some helpful links and steps to take?